# What is the status of Monogame now that XNA has been discontinued?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, monogame

XNA has officially been discontinued, with support no longer being offered by Microsoft. Does this mean that Monogame has died also? I see that the site still says it is based upon XNA 4. What is the official status of Monogame?

Comment: I don't see how XNA getting discontinued would affect Monogame at all.  Their whole goal is to have an open source implementation of the XNA API (as far as I know).  They have a roadmap on their github page: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame

Comment: My suspicion is that Microsoft wanted to move away from the idea of people coding platform-specific games in their proprietary language. Microsoft XNA fell under that filter, but MonoGame didn't. I think knowing they were going to be third wheel in the tablet gaming world, they wanted to very much prefer people use cross-platform engines rather than go Microsoft-only. MonoGame may yet advance with whatever features people want, as they control it all themselves.

Comment: @Katana314 - my suspicion is that you're just being paranoid.  Microsoft have a new console coming out, it's D3D11-level hardware, XNA is D3D9-level, *of course* XNA is going to be discontinued.  Occam's razor says I'm right.  Either way, and since this question can't go anywhere good, voting to close.

Comment: @mh01: "*it's D3D11-level hardware, XNA is D3D9-level, of course XNA is going to be discontinued*" Actually, that doesn't follow. Epic didn't discontinue the Unreal Engine; they simply made a *new* version for new hardware and consoles. Microsoft could have made a new version of XNA, but they didn't. Granted, I don't buy Katana's logic for why they did; it seems much more reasonable to assume that they simply don't care to fund support of it.

Comment: XNA 4.0 was moving towards D3D11 support, as it dropped all the D3D9-only features. (Also apparently the WP7 version of XNA was a partial D3D11 implementation). So it's not because of D3D versions that XNA got canned.

Answer (score 7):

Quite the opposite. MonoGame stands to be the perfect replacement for existing XNA developers. It doesn't do everything that XNA did yet but there's no good reason why it can't. Coupled with the fact that it sports many more platforms and it's already being used in many reputable games I'm confident it will be great for some time to come.

Edit: I wrote this answer on my phone, let me elaborate a little more.

Firstly, MonoGame does not depend on XNA, it's an open source implementation of the XNA API and does *not* use Microsoft's implementation in any way. They make it clear in the  [Contributing to MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Contributing-to-MonoGame) instructions that no code from the XNA framework is actually used in the implementation, only the public API. Therefore, MonoGame exists on it's own without XNA.

Secondly, the MonoGame project is being actively developed. You can see on github there is plenty of [commit activity](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/graphs/commit-activity) going on. The most recent post on their website was 2 days ago announcing 2 MonoGame titles coming to PS4.

Third, the [MonoGame forums](https://community.monogame.net) are active. The most recent posts are today, and plenty of discussions going on around development, new game announcements, new platform support and solving problems. They also have other active social feeds like twitter and as Noctrine pointed out an ["official status"](https://twitter.com/MonoGameTeam/status/345301738938576896)

So, there's plenty of evidence to indicate that MonoGame has not died.

Comment: I believe the question asked for an "official status"...

Comment: Essentially this - https://twitter.com/monogameteam/status/345301738938576896

Comment: @Noctrine seems like that should be an answer.

Comment: No MonoGame depends on XNA installed since Monogame has no implementation of the content pipeline yet.

Comment: You don't have to use the XNA content pipeline. MonoGame supports loading content from raw files (.png, .wav, etc) directly. I've made full games without XNA installed. That said, this question is about the status of MonoGame and even if you do still use the XNA content pipeline, MonoGame continues to work both now and in the future with or without XNA.

Comment: You cannot load models without the original XNA Content Pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

hmm i have been working on a project for 4 years now, 4 years ago i put it aside, because there were too many bugs in Monogame. I continued the work 2 month ago, only to struggle with the exact same issue i did back then (4 years ago), it still doesnt work, and its still full of bugs and memory leaks. :( - Many of the bugs has been found years ago (2016), and reported and even talked about by the developers, but they are still not fixed. I have a hard time seeing how this will ever be production ready, im planning to switch to Unity, as the majority. - Too bad my new 3D Engine (writte in XNA, attempted ported to Monogame will never be a reality) :( as im 98% done with it.